# How do you reuse a protobuf message in another message without assigning another field?

Tags: protocol-buffers

If I have a protobuf message like this:

```
message Hostnames {
  message Hostname {
    string hostname = 1;
    uint32 port = 2;
  }
  repeated Hostname hostnames = 1;
}
```

If I want to use that message in another message, how do I avoid assigning another field? Example:

```
message Backends {
  Hostnames hostnames = 1;
}
```

This seems like in YAML it would appear like this:

```
backends:
  hostnames:
    hostnames:
      - hostname: one.example.com
        port: 80
      - hostname: two.example.com
        port: 80
```

But what I want is just:

```
backends:
  hostnames:
    - hostname: one.example.com
      port: 80
    - hostname: two.example.com
      port: 80
```

Comment: To do that you would remove the `Hostnames` type and just use `repeated Hostname hostnames = N;` where needed. Obviously move the `Hostname` type out a level first.

Comment: There are other users on the project, and I want to enforce a repeated Hostname otherwise some might use just a single Hostname.  Is there no other way?

Comment: no; but changing from single to repeated isn't impossible - it isn't binary breaking at the format layer, but: only the last value will be retained on apps that don't use repeated